# Calls to Wcf service are denied? Is this problem with the web config?

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, wcf-security

I have a WCF service... which will reside on Azure. I added forms authentication and authorization via the following configuration in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="blah.svc" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="blah" applicationName="blah_app" name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <add name="SqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="blah" applicationName="blah_app" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="blah" applicationName="blah_app" name="SqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="wsHttp">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="SqlRoleProvider" />
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="blah_cert" />
                    </serviceCredentials>

                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="blah_app.blah" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttp">
                <endpoint address="" contract="blah_app.iblah" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

the problem I am getting is that any of the calls to the web service from the client are comming as Denied!

```
public class Blah:IBlah
{
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "BlahOppRole")]
        public BlahResponse Blah(BlahRequest BlahRequest)
        {
            BlahResponse = new BlahResponse();


            return response;
        }
}
```

My client is a windows console app. It has the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBlah" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Digest" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:89/Blah.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBlah"
                contract="Data.Blah" name="WSHttpBinding_IBlah">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="blah_cert"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
```

Comment: I double checked to make sure the current user has the "BlahOppRole" and has sufficient username and password via that WAT (Website Administration Tool). However no-matter what I do I get an Access Denied response! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you access the .svc with IE?

Comment: When I run it from within vs I can access it. I see the screen where it says "You have created a service. To test this you will need to create a client... and so forth". So yes. I always refresh the reference to the service in my client and everything is fine. However the user is not being Authorized to the particular method call based on the configured roles, which is why I am having the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648840.aspx) gives a good step-by-step instruction on how to configure WsHttpBinding with UserName authentication.

Basically you will have to

- Set security mode to `TransportWithMessageCredential` (Step 6)
- Add a `ServiceCredentials` service behavior and configure `userNameAuthentication` (Step 8)
- Modify your Client application to set the UserName and Password (Step 12)

Comment: All said and done, I had to do something a bit different. When using X509 Certificate (Self Signed Certificate for SSL) the client has an issue validating the cert. In this case you have to create a client end point behavior, and specify a custom X509 Certificate validator in order to fool the client that the cert is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
Since I was using a self signed certificate... the client was throwing a fit about the authenticity of that certificate. Common errors were AccessDenied, (due to misconfiguration of the service), as well "Error occured while negotiating the service credential..." or something along the lines. Long story short, after reading the post of this fine fellow (Thank you Dev @ Work) [Dev @ Work](http://www.devatwork.nl/2007/05/wcf-username-authentication/) I was able to modify his work and add ASP.NET forms authentication and authorization via Membership and Role providers on the service.

To sum it up, Dev @ Work had a very valid point. WCF clients will scream about self signed certificates. The trick to making a wcf service useful on a dev server is to lie to the service clients about the authenticity of the certificate used to encode the client's credentials. To do so, any wcf client has to have a **behaviorConfiguration** to its **serviceEndpoint** and use custom certificate validation mechanism to authenticate the server's certificate. This is done by creating an object that inherits from the **System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator** and by overriding the `Validate()` method of said object. The validation is successful if the said object doesn't throw errors:

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://machine:5101/blah.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_Iblah"
                contract="Data.Iblah" name="WsHttpBinding_Iblah" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorConfig">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="..." />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>

        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BehaviorConfig">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="BlahConsole.X509Validator, BlahConsole"/>
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>        
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

And the custom validator:

```
internal class X509Validator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            // validate argument
            if (certificate == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Certificate is null");
        }
    }
```